# why compareTo method return difference between to strings(ascii) value

Tags: java

"xyz".compareTo("abc")--->23

"abc".compareTo("xyz")--->-23

I need to know how it is calculating this number value.what is the use of this value

Answer (score 7):

Please look at the source code and go through the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29), *which says Compares two strings **lexicographically**.The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings.*

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        char c1 = v1[k];
        char c2 = v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

**Case 1:** `"xyz".compareTo("abc")`

shall return `'x'-'a'` which is equal to 23.

**Case 2:** `"abc".compareTo("xyz")`

shall return `'a'-'x'` which is equal to -23.

Answer (score 3):

The *magnitude* of the value is irrelevant, and shouldn't generally be relied upon. The exact value is documented for `String.compareTo`, but I regard that as a design mistake in itself. It's not like the difference can be *used* in any sensible fashion, and it restricts later implementations which could still obey the contract of `Comparable` but with different details :( (The fact that `String.hashCode` is completely specified is a similar mistake.)

All that's important for an ordering comparison is whether the value is less than 0, 0, or greater than 0.

From the docs of [`Comparable.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

> **Returns:**
>   a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers: if you want to perform local-sensitve String comparison rather than lexicographically (e.g. for natural language texts), then have a look at [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) and [CollationKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/CollationKey.html).

Answer (score 0):

compareTo value is only refer to the sign of the result
+ means that this bigger than the argument xyz > abc
- means that this smaller than the argument abc < xyz
0 means they are equals.

since trings contains charecters, the compareTo of strings use the lexicgraphical order and transform it to numbers but this is only the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> "xyz".compareTo("abc")--->23

This is required to return a positive integer. In this case it is returning 'x'-'a', which is 23.

> "abc".compareTo("xyz")--->-23

This is required to return a negative integer. In this case it is returning 'a'-'x', which is -23.

Similarly

```
"abc".compareTo("abc")---> 0
```

This is required to return zero. In this case it would return 'a'-'a', which is zero.

You can see that using subtraction is the easiest way to implement the contract.